# How to export datasource type as array in datagrid, Orocommerce

Tags: datagrid, orocommerce

I created an array-based datagrid from datagrid.yml, but I don't know how to export the datagrid's data to a csv or excel file.
I'm using the onBuildAfter method in the listener to stuff the array data into the datagrid.

datagrid.yml:

```
 test-demo-lookup-grid:
    options:
        export:
            csv: { label: oro.grid.export.csv }
    source:
        type: array
    columns:
        id:
            label: 'ID'
        ot:
            label: 'OT'
```

listener:

```
public function onBuildAfter(BuildAfter $event)
{
    $datagrid = $event->getDatagrid();
    $datasource = $datagrid->getDatasource();

    if (!$datasource instanceof ArrayDatasource) {
        throw new UnexpectedTypeException($datasource, ArrayDatasource::class);
    }
    $recordsJsonObj = $this->getParameter($datagrid, 'records');

    if (!empty($recordsJsonObj)) {
        $records = json_decode($recordsJsonObj);

        $datasource->setArraySource($records);
    }
}
enter code here
```